# Как задать sql-запрос?

Tags: oracle, sql

Есть 2 таблицы

```
table 1
id  name value
1    a         14
2    b         1
5    e          32
```

---

```
table2
id name value
1    a       13
2    b       12
3    c       11
4    d       11
```

Итак, нужно сделать выборку, если id присутствует и в той и другой таблице, тогда выбираем строку из второй таблицы. Если же id из первой или второй таблицы уникальный, тогда такая строка должна попасть в выборку
Результат

```
result_table
id name value
1    a       13
2    b       12
3    c       11
4    d       11
5    e       32
```

Как задать sql запрос? Есть соответствующий join?
oracle без программных расширений

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает что очередную проблему решают "правильно"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
NVL(table2.id, table1.id),
NVL(table2.name, table1.name),
NVL(table2.value, table1.value)
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2 on table2.id=table1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table2
union all
select * from table1 where id not in(select id from table2)
```

Comment: table1 и 2 формируются запросом, мне кажется вариант предложенный regenerator-ом будет быстрее

Comment: 1. Я не работаю с Ораклом. Сравните планы.
2. Если вы хотели получить наиболее производительный запрос, то нужно было указать это в своем вопросе.